# Get error when displaying a token in a header view

Tags: views, display-suite

I have a view working fine. Now I added a header text (Global Text) printing a token for the first contextual filter :

```
<?php print t('Subastas de ') . !1 ; ?>
```

The token is printed right but I get this error. The token value is: DIBUJO

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant DIBUJO - assumed 'DIBUJO' en eval() (línea 1 de /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/subastaspintura.com/sites/all/modules/ds/ds.module(954) : eval()'d code).
```

In this capture you can see how the Global text header is set up:
[image]

Comment: I think you can do it without PHP code. Just enter "Subastes de !1". Or does this not work?

Comment: You are right I set Plain text and get it working. Thanks. Do you mind moving your comment to an answer to allow me to accept it as right answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it without PHP code. Just enter "Subastes de !1".